# Connect Laravel App on Heroku to my external MySql Database

Tags: mysql, laravel, heroku

I have uploaded my Laravel project to Heroku and I want to use my own database. It is hosted on a VPS. 
I have been using that DB from my computer and it worked fine but when I deploy my app it throws a Connection time out error.

I have used the following command to set up the connection:

```
heroku config:add DATABASE_URL=mysql://user:pass@server:port/database_name
```

Any idea on how can I achieve this? Or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Laravel doesn't know by default how to use the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable you are setting.

I think you should probably run these commands

```
heroku config:add DB_HOST=server
heroku config:add DB_PORT=port
heroku config:add DB_USERNAME=user
heroku config:add DB_PASSWORD=pass
heroku config:add DB_DATABASE=database_name
```

Of course, change the values accordingly with your server configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately it still does not work. Maybe the vps is blocking the connection, but I'm unable to get my app's IP to whitelist it since it's  dynamic :S

Comment: if you have a VPS you should have great control on incoming connections. If you are able to connect it from your local machine (And you didn't whitelist its IP) you should not have problems connecting from an heroku instance.